# smartparens insert single versus paired character?

Tags: smartparens

**Q:** how can I tweak `smartparens`'s decision rules for when to
  insert a paired or single character?

`smartparens` seems to be *mostly* smart when inserting single
quotes (e.g., in `text-mode` or `org-mode`).  Hence, it default to
inserting a pair of `'`s and placing the cursor in between them,
but, when invoked at the end of a word, only inserts a single `'`
in anticipation of contractions.  So, e.g.:

- `'` => `'*'` (where `*` is point)
- `can + '` => `can'*` (so I can continue to write "can't")

However, there's a hiccup I'm looking to fix.  I often use
abbreviations that end in a period, but would like to make them
possessive.  For example, I might write "s.o." as an abbreviation
for "someone," and therefore "s.o.'s" would be "someone's."  The
problem is that `smartparens` inserts a paired-`'` after a period:

- what I want: `s.o. + '` => `s.o.'*`
- what I get: `s.o. + '` => `s.o.'*'`

My specific quibble is with `smartparens`'s behavior on `'`, but I
can imagine this being a more general issue with other characters
as well.

So: *how can I tweak `smartparens`'s decision rule to expand the
set of characters after which it only inserts a single `'`?*

*PS: amusingly, trying to type "`smartparens`'s" in emacs gives the same irritating behavior.*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with pairing conditionals:

```el
;; a sample from my .emacs.d
(defun my-sp-pair-function (id action context)
  (if (eq action 'insert)
    ;; t to pair, nil to not pair
    (or (looking-at "[[:space:][:punct:]]")
      (sp-point-before-eol-p id action context))
    t))

(with-eval-after-load 'smartparens
    (sp-pair "(" ")" :when '(my-sp-pair-function) :wrap "C-)")
    (sp-pair "{" "}" :when '(my-sp-pair-function) :wrap "C-}")
    (sp-pair "[" "]" :when '(my-sp-pair-function) :wrap "C-]")
    (sp-pair "\"" "\"" :when '(my-sp-pair-function) :wrap "C-\"")
    (sp-pair "'" "'" :when '(my-sp-pair-function)))
```

Comment: The lower part looks totally unrelated. The upper part looks like it won't do anything on its own. Could you please turn your answer into something functional?

Comment: That is true... copy-paste fail. Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, but `my-sp-pair-function` does not appear to be providing the desired functionality.  It's giving me the same behavior as before after punctuation (paired insert), but now it also does a paired-insert after alphanumeric characters as well, breaking the contractions.

Comment: @Dan, this was meant to be a general solution. You can, for example replace the condition with this: `(and (or (looking-at "[[:space:][:punct:]]") (sp-point-before-eol-p id action context)) (not (looking-back "[.\`]")))`

Answer (score 2):

You can modify smartparen's behavior by using the functions `sp-pair` and `sp-local-pair`. The smartparens [wiki](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Pair-management) explains these functions in detail.

Basically you can something like following to customize the behavior globally

```
(sp-pair "\"" nil :unless '(my-custom-predicate))
```

OR to customize the behavior just for some modes

```
(sp-local-pair desired-modes "\"" nil :unless '(my-custom-predicate))
```

where `desired-mode` is the mode for which you want to customize the behavior and `my-custom-predicate` is function that smartparens should use to determine whether it should insert the pair automatically.

From `sp-pair`'s docstring the custom predicate should accept

> opening delimiter (which uniquely determines the pair), action and
>   context.  The context argument can have values:
>
> - string  - if point is inside string.
> - comment - if point is inside comment.
> - code    - if point is inside code.  This context is only   recognized in programming modes that define string semantics.

So a custom function that can be used as a `:unless` predicate in your specific case would be something like the following

```
(defun predp (id action context)
  (sp--looking-back-p "[[:punct:]]'"))
```

Notice that I am checking for the regex `<punctuation>'` since the point would be at `.'|` when the predicate is executing.

Finally, you can hook it into smartparens by doing

```
(sp-pair  "'" nil :unless'(predp))
```

Comment: Thanks, that gets me part of the way there, but could you provide a concrete example?  I've tried various forms of the predicate function (eg,`(defun predp () (sp--looking-back-p "[[:space:][:punct:]]"))`), but `smartparens` ignores them all.

Comment: Hi @Dan, I have added the solution for your specific problem to the answer. You were not accepting the required arguments in the predicate, also the regex used was slightly off